# perf not displaying source code in annotations, despite symbols being included

Tags: linux, profiling, perf

In annotations, `perf` only displays assembly code to me.  However, it does correctly list all the symbols, and the binary is compiled with `-g`.  Further, `file` lists the binary as `with debug_info, not stripped`.

I compile with

```
 clang -std=c89 -pedantic -g \
        -Wno-attributes \
        -foptimize-sibling-calls \
        -fno-strict-aliasing \
        -DNDEBUG \
        *.c
```

and then record with `perf record -g --call-graph dwarf ./a.out [file arg to a.out]`.  However, when running `perf annotate` or going into annotation mode from `perf report -g`, only assembly code is displayed.  I've tried passing `--source` and `-l`, but neither seem to change anything.

I'm on Artix, using `perf version 6.1.g830b3c68c1fb` (`perf-6.1-1` in repos).

Comment: Same problem on `perf  6.3-4`.

Answer (score 2):

Try compiling with `-gdwarf-4`; there seems to be some problems with [DWARF-5](https://discourse.llvm.org/t/bin-ld-dwarf-error-invalid-or-unhandled-form-value-0x25/67620).

Comment: That thread speaks about linker issues, doesn't it? Not perf.